# Как правильно прочитать .cfg-файл из blob-поля БД

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

в поле в БД храниться .cfg-файл.
Как правильно выгрузить этот файл что бы можно было библиотекой configparser читать?

Comment: А что за бд? Какая библиотека используется для работы с бд?

Comment: mysql, библиотека pymysql

Comment: Считать значение того поля в строку и использовать метод `read_string` у https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html